# Why don't use Lubuntu's windows the whole screen?

Tags: lubuntu, window

I have installed Lubuntu on my old PC, and changed the screen resolution from 1024x768 to bigger. If I want to maximize a window, it uses not the whole but only a small area with 1024x768 pixels in the upper left corner. The situation is the same by the shutdown screen. What can I do to resolve this?

Thank you for your help!